# A trigger before insert raises an error when called an insert using custom client but not when using MySQL client

Tags: mysql, c, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

Hello and thank you to anyone who's willing to help me out.

I'm coding a MySQL db schema called `directory_aziendale` (company directory), which has to track all employers of a company, their jobs, their seats in the offices and their relocations beetween offices.
I have coded a Stored Procedure called `scambiaDipendenti` (switchEmployers). When called, it switches the seats of the provided employers only if they are currently assigned to the same job, inserting in table `TRASFERITO_A` (transferred to) the employer, the telephone number of the seat where the employer is transferred to, the date and the job.
A before insert trigger of `TRASFERITO_A` aborts the insert if the employer was already assigned to that seat in the past three years. To check this, it uses the dates saved in `TRASFERITO_A`
I have emptied the table `TRASFERITO_A` and called `scambiaDipendenti` using a prepared statement, and this was the ouptut, which matches the expected behaviour:

```
mysql> prepare stmt from "call scambiaDipendenti(?, ?)"
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from TRASFERITO_A;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
mysql> set @b = "TXHTGD97E65H851W"
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
 
mysql> set @a = "LNYRYM72A08Z327C"
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
 
mysql> execute stmt using @a, @b;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
 
mysql> select * from TRASFERITO_A;
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+
| CFDipendente     | NumTelefonicoEsternoPostazione | Data       | NomeMansione     | NomeSettore  |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+
| TXHTGD97E65H851W | 1230987654                     | 2020-09-06 | calcolo bilancio | contabilità  |
| LNYRYM72A08Z327C | 8582484945                     | 2020-09-06 | calcolo bilancio | contabilità  |
+------------------+--------------------------------+------------+------------------+--------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm also writing a thin client in C using the MySQL C API to interact with the DB calling some operations. An operation of them prepares the same statemnt, and this was the output:

```
$ ./debug dipendenteSettoreSpazi
[I] DirAz Thin Client - connector for directory_aziendale DB
[I] Please enter password:
[I] Succesfully logged in as dipendenteSettoreSpazi
[I] Here is a list of supported operations. Please note that You must have the correct privileges for an operation in order to execute it. For executing an operation, opCode followed by its arguments (i.e: opCode [arg0, ...])
[I] op1: generaReportDaTrasferire()
[I] op2_1: trovaDipendentiScambiabili(cfDipendente)
[I] op2_2: scambiaDipendenti(cfDipendente1, cfDipendente2)
[I] op3_1: trovaUfficiConPostazioneVuota(nomeMansione, nomeSettore)
[I] op3_2: assegnaDipendenteAPostazioneVuota(cfDipendente, numTelefonicoEsternoPostazioneVuota)
[I] op4: cambiaMansioneDipendente(cfDipendente, nomeNuovaMansione, nomeNuovoSettore)
[I] op5: elencaTrasferimentiDipendente(cfDipendente)
[I] op6: ricercaDipendente(nome, cognome)
[I] op7: ricercaPerNumeroTelefono(numTelefonoEsterno)
[I] op9: assumiDipendente(cf, nome, cognome, luogoNascita, dataNascita, emailPersonale, indirizzoResidenza, nomeMansione, nomeSettore)
[I] Type here:
op2_2 LNYRYM72A08Z327C TXHTGD97E65H851W
[D] 45004
[E] mysql_stmt_execute: ERROR: Un dipendente non può essere trasferito a una postazione dove è stato già trasferito meno di tre anni fa
[E] failed to launch statement
[E] failed to prepare and launch statement
[E] Failed to execute op2_2
```

`scambiaDipendenti` failed with sqlstatus 45004, which means the before insert trigger of TRASFERITO_A failed.

My question is: how come the same trigger didn't raised an error when `scambiaDipendenti` was called by MySQL client and failed when was called by my thin client?

Here are the sources. op2_2 is the op code for `scambiaDipendenti`.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `scambiaDipendenti`(
    in cfDipendente1 char(16), 
    in cfDipendente2 char(16)
)
BEGIN
    declare tempNumeroTelefonico1 varchar(45);
    declare tempNumeroTelefonico2 varchar(45);
    declare tempNomeMansione varchar(45);
    declare tempNomeSettore varchar(45);
    declare exit handler for sqlexception
    begin
        rollback;
        resignal;
    end;
    start transaction;
    -- controlla se le due postazioni appartengono ad uffici fisici assegnati alla stessa mansione e settore, che verranno salvati dentro delle variabili
    call checkDipendentiStessaMansione(cfDipendente1, cfDipendente2, tempNomeMansione, tempNomeSettore);
    if (tempNomeMansione is null and tempNomeSettore is null) 
        then signal sqlstate "45005" set message_text = "ERROR: i dipendenti forniti non sono assegnati alla stessa mansione";
    end if;
    -- scambia i dipendenti e aggiorna la tabella TRASFERITO_A atomicamente
    set tempNumeroTelefonico1 = (select NumTelefonicoEsternoPostazione from DIPENDENTE where CF = cfDipendente1);
    set tempNumeroTelefonico2 = (select NumTelefonicoEsternoPostazione from DIPENDENTE where CF = cfDipendente2);
    update DIPENDENTE set NumTelefonicoEsternoPostazione = null where CF = cfDipendente1;
    update DIPENDENTE set NumTelefonicoEsternoPostazione = null where CF = cfDipendente2;
    insert into TRASFERITO_A values (cfDipendente1, tempNumeroTelefonico2, curdate(), tempNomeMansione, tempNomeSettore);
    insert into TRASFERITO_A values (cfDipendente2, tempNumeroTelefonico1, curdate(), tempNomeMansione, tempNomeSettore);
    commit;
END
```

```
CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `directory_aziendale`.`TRASFERITO_A_BEFORE_INSERT`
BEFORE INSERT ON `directory_aziendale`.`TRASFERITO_A`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if (select CFDipendente from DA_TRASFERIRE_A where new.CFDipendente = DA_TRASFERIRE_A.CFDipendente) is not null
        then delete from DA_TRASFERIRE_A where new.CFDipendente = DA_TRASFERIRE_A.CFDipendente;
        end if;
    if (select NumTelefonicoEsternoPostazione 
        from TRASFERITO_A 
        where TRASFERITO_A.NumTelefonicoEsternoPostazione = new.NumTelefonicoEsternoPostazione 
            and TRASFERITO_A.CFDipendente = new.CFDipendente
            and timestampdiff(year, TRASFERITO_A.`Data`, curdate()) <= 3 
    ) is not null
        then signal sqlstate '45004' set message_text = "ERROR: Un dipendente non può essere trasferito a una postazione dove è stato già trasferito meno di tre anni fa";
    end if;
END
```

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <mysql_time.h>

#include "controller.h"
#include "logger.h"

#define MAX_LENGTH 1024

struct op {
    const char* name;
    const char* params;
    const char* stmt;
};

static const char* db_name = "directory_aziendale";
static const char* host_name = "localhost";
static struct op operations[NUM_OPS];
static char *opStrings[NUM_OPS];

void initController(){
    // populates opStrings with literal form of opCode
    // ...
    opStrings[op2_2] = "op2_2";
    
    // ...

    // Populates structures in operations with data for each op. (TODO: data should be read from a file)
    // ...
    operations[op2_2].name = "scambiaDipendenti";
    operations[op2_2].params = "cfDipendente1, cfDipendente2";
    operations[op2_2].stmt = "call scambiaDipendenti(?, ?)";

    // ...

}

int prepareOp(MYSQL *conn, enum opCode op, MYSQL_STMT **stmtAddr){
    // init stmt
    if ((*stmtAddr = mysql_stmt_init(conn)) == NULL){
        logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_init: %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        return 1;
    }
    // prepares stmt
    MYSQL_STMT *stmt = *stmtAddr;
    if (mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, operations[op].stmt, strlen(operations[op].stmt)) != 0){
        logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_prepare: %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int launchOp(MYSQL *conn, MYSQL_STMT *stmt, MYSQL_BIND *inParams){
    // bind params
    if (inParams != NULL && mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt, inParams)){
        logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_bind_param: %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
        return 1;
    }

    // execute statement
    if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt)){
        logMsg(D, "%s\n", mysql_sqlstate(conn));
        logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_execute: %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
        return 1;
    }
    // buffers result set
    if (mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt) != 0){
        logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_store_result: %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int prepareAndLaunchOp(MYSQL *conn, enum opCode op, MYSQL_BIND *inParams, MYSQL_STMT **stmtAddr){
    // prepares stmt
    if (prepareOp(conn, op, stmtAddr)){
        logMsg(E, "failed to prepare statement\n");
        return 1;
    }
    MYSQL_STMT *stmt = *stmtAddr;
    // launches op
    if (launchOp(conn, stmt, inParams)){
        logMsg(E, "failed to launch statement\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int printRes(MYSQL_STMT* stmt, MYSQL_RES *metaRes, MYSQL_BIND *resultSetCols){
    mysql_field_seek(metaRes, 0);
    int resNumCol = mysql_num_fields(metaRes);
    int width[resNumCol], res;
    logMsg(I, " )   ");
    for (int c = 0; c < resNumCol; c ++){
        printf("%s%n | ", mysql_fetch_field(metaRes) -> name, width + c);
    }
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    for (int r = 0; ; r ++){
        if ((res = mysql_stmt_fetch(stmt)) == MYSQL_NO_DATA){
            break;
        }
        switch(res) {
            case 1:
                logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_fetch: %d\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
                return 1;
            case MYSQL_DATA_TRUNCATED:
                logMsg(W, "data truncation occurred\n", r);
            case 0:
                break;
        }
        logMsg(I, "%d) ", r);
        for (int c = 0; c < resNumCol; c ++){
            switch((resultSetCols + c) -> buffer_type){
            case MYSQL_TYPE_STRING:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_VAR_STRING:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_NEWDECIMAL:
                printf("%*s | ", width[c], (*((bool *) ((resultSetCols + c) -> is_null)))? "NULL" : (char *) resultSetCols[c].buffer);
                break;
            case MYSQL_TYPE_TINY:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_SHORT:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_INT24:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_LONG:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG:
                if (*((bool *) ((resultSetCols + c) -> is_null))){
                    printf("%*s | ", width[c], "NULL");
                }
                else {
                    printf("%*d | ", width[c], *((int *)(resultSetCols[c].buffer)));
                }
                break;
            case MYSQL_TYPE_FLOAT:
            case MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE:
                if (*((bool *) ((resultSetCols + c) -> is_null))){
                    printf("%*s | ", width[c], "NULL");
                }
                else {
                    printf("%*f | ", width[c], *((double *)(resultSetCols[c].buffer)));
                }
                break;
            case MYSQL_TYPE_DATE:
                if (*((bool *) ((resultSetCols + c) -> is_null))){
                    printf("%s/ ", "NULL");
                }
                else {
                    printf("%d/%d/%d | ",
                        ((MYSQL_TIME *)(resultSetCols[c].buffer)) -> day,
                        ((MYSQL_TIME *)(resultSetCols[c].buffer)) -> month,
                        ((MYSQL_TIME *)(resultSetCols[c].buffer)) -> year
                    );
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("(not supported) | ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}

void freeResultSet(MYSQL_BIND *resultSetCols, int resNumCol){
   for (int i = 0; i < resNumCol; i ++){
        free(resultSetCols[i].buffer);
        free(resultSetCols[i].length);
        free(resultSetCols[i].is_null);
        free(resultSetCols[i].error);
    }
    free(resultSetCols);
}

MYSQL_BIND *callocResultSetCols(MYSQL_RES *metaRes){
    int resNumCol = mysql_num_fields(metaRes);
    MYSQL_BIND *resultSetCols = calloc(resNumCol, sizeof(MYSQL_BIND));
    MYSQL_FIELD *currentField;

    mysql_field_seek(metaRes, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < resNumCol; i ++){
    currentField = mysql_fetch_field(metaRes);
    resultSetCols[i].buffer_type = currentField -> type;
    resultSetCols[i].buffer = calloc(MAX_LENGTH, sizeof(char));
    resultSetCols[i].buffer_length  = MAX_LENGTH;
    resultSetCols[i].length = (unsigned long*) calloc(1, sizeof(unsigned long));
    resultSetCols[i].is_null = (bool *) calloc(1, sizeof(bool));
    resultSetCols[i].error = (bool *) calloc(1, sizeof(bool));
    }
    return resultSetCols;
}

int bindRes(MYSQL_STMT *stmt, MYSQL_BIND **resultSetColsAddr, MYSQL_RES **metaResAddr){
    MYSQL_RES *metaRes;
    MYSQL_BIND *resultSetCols;
    int resNumCol;
    int numRes = 0;
    if ((*metaResAddr = mysql_stmt_result_metadata(stmt)) == NULL){
            logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_result_metadata: %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
            return -1;
    }
    metaRes = *metaResAddr;
    resNumCol = mysql_num_fields(metaRes);
    if (resNumCol > 0){
        numRes ++;
        // binds result set dinamically
        *resultSetColsAddr = callocResultSetCols(metaRes);
        resultSetCols = *resultSetColsAddr;
        if (mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt, resultSetCols)){
            logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_bind_result: %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return numRes;
}

// ...

int callOp2_2(MYSQL *conn, int numOfArgs, char *cfDipendente1, char *cfDipendente2){
    MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
    MYSQL_BIND *resSet;
    MYSQL_BIND *inParams = calloc(numOfArgs, sizeof(MYSQL_BIND));
    MYSQL_RES *metaRes;
    int hasNext;
    unsigned long len[numOfArgs];
    bool isNull[numOfArgs];

    // prepares params

    memset(isNull, false, sizeof(bool) * numOfArgs);

    if (cfDipendente1 == NULL){
        cfDipendente1 = "";
        isNull[0] = true;
        inParams -> is_null = isNull;
    }
    len[0] = sizeof(char) * strlen(cfDipendente1);
    inParams -> buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    inParams -> buffer = cfDipendente1;
    inParams -> buffer_length = len[0];
    inParams -> length = len;

    if (cfDipendente2 == NULL){
        cfDipendente2 = "";
        isNull[1] = true;
        (inParams + 1) -> is_null = isNull;
    }
    len[1] = sizeof(char) * strlen(cfDipendente2);
    (inParams + 1) -> buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    (inParams + 1) -> buffer = cfDipendente2;
    (inParams+ 1) -> buffer_length = len[1];
    (inParams + 1) -> length = len + 1;

    // prepare and launches stmt
    if (prepareAndLaunchOp(conn, op2_2, inParams, &stmt)){
        logMsg(E, "failed to prepare and launch statement\n");
        return 1;
    }


    // binds res set
    if (bindRes(stmt, &resSet, &metaRes) <= 0){
        logMsg(W, "Either failed to bind a result set or no result set was available to bind\n");
    }

    // no res set has to be printed

    // discards remaining result sets
    do {mysql_stmt_free_result(stmt);} while ((hasNext = mysql_stmt_next_result(stmt) == 0));
    if (hasNext > 0){
        logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_next_result: %s\n", mysql_stmt_error(stmt));
        return 1;
    }

    // frees memory allocated dinamically
    freeResultSet(resSet, mysql_num_fields(metaRes));
    mysql_free_result(metaRes);
    if (mysql_stmt_close(stmt) != 0){
        logMsg(E, "mysql_stmt_close: %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// ...

int callOp(MYSQL *conn, const enum opCode op, char *opArgs){
    // TODO: Binding of in and out params and collecting the result set are demanded to the particular op
    int res;
    switch(op){
        // ...
        case op2_2:
            //FIXME: sqlstate 45004 caught even if TRASFERITO_A is empty. Calling scambiaDipendenti with MySQl client result in success
            res = callOp2_2(conn, 2, strtok(opArgs, ARG_DEL), strtok(NULL, ARG_DEL));
            break;
        // ...
        default:
            logMsg(E, "There is no such operation with provided opCode\n");
            return 1;
    }
    return res;
}

int connectToDB(char *username, char* passwd, MYSQL** connAddr){
    // Initialize connection
    if ((*connAddr = mysql_init(NULL)) == NULL){
        int err = errno;
        logMsg(E, "mysql_init: %s\n", strerror(err));
        return 1;
    }
    MYSQL *conn = *connAddr;
    // Tries to connect with db. NULL values are read from settings file
    if ((mysql_real_connect(conn,
                        host_name,
                        username,
                        passwd,
                        db_name,
                        0, // port number
                        NULL, // socket name
                        CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS )) == NULL){
        logMsg(E, "mysql_real_connect: %s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

// ...
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is way too much code for us to debug for you, while you can pretty easily actually debug this. Apparently, your trigger throws an error because the condition is met, and you don't think it should be. Go backwards from there and check when this differs. Usual suspects are: 1. you didn't empty the table. 2. you didn't call the procedure with the parameters you think you did. 3. you called the procedure twice. For starters, I would just remove the check/signal in the trigger and check if the outcome fits your expectation (e.g. the content of the 2 tables). Then add more logs.

Comment: I posted lots of code because I had no idea why the error was raised only if the procedure was called by the client, thus I had no idea what piece of code I should have posted. I knew that was too much code, and I'm sorry for this, but I thought  I had no choice.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the error, it was in callOp2_2:

```
// ...

bool isNull[numOfArgs];

// ...

if (cfDipendente2 == NULL){
        cfDipendente1 = "";
        isNull[1] = true;
        inParams -> is_null = isNull;  // it should be inParams -> is_null = isNull + 1
    }
```

This caused to pass undefined values to bind for the prepared statement, thus leading to unpredictable errors.